# C# ListView : How to Scroll it Vertically in List mode (normally its horizontal scroll bar is shown When View = List)?

Tags: list, listview, c#-2.0, scrollbar

When C#(.net 2.0) list view is in List mode(see the code below):

```
this.listView1.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.List;
```

the list view scroll bar that is enabled is horizontal scroll bar(when list view items can't fit into the space available).

But I want to enable vertical scroll bar, how?

Answer (score 0):

Use,

```
this.listView1.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details;
```

instead of

```
this.listView1.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.List;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
`this.listView1.View = System.Windows.Form.View.Details;`
 instead of 
`this.listView1.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.List;`.
It's very hard to display content in a single line.